# Using <= in Subquery to output results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a query that first declares and inserts data into a temporary table. This table is being used to filter out the main table in sql server that contains customer data.

Query with dummy data filled into temp table is as follows:

```
Declare @myInputTable TABLE (Customer_input INT, Date_of_interest bigint)
insert into @myInputTable values(12345, '20140924'),(22234,'20210508')

select top 1
MainTable.CustomerID,
MainTable.PurchaseDate
From MainTable
Where (customerID in (select Customer_input from @myInputTable) and PurchaseDate <= (select Date_of_interest from @myInputTable))
```

When I comment out the 2nd customer+date of interest the query runs normally and gives me the result, but moment it deals with multiple customer and date of interest combinations it spits out the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I understand that the problem lies in "PurchaseDate <=...", but I am not sure how else I can filter out results to match customerIDs and only output the closest purchase date records to the date of interest of each customer. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Test data from MainTable:

| CustomerID | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 20150120 |
| 12345 | 20140213 |
| 12345 | 20120811 |
| 22234 | 20210419 |
| 22234 | 20220322 |

Expected result from the query overall:

| CustomerID | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 20140213 |
| 22234 | 20210419 |

The query should rule out all PurchaseDate that are >Date_of_interest and only display the closest past PurchaseDate to Date_of_interest of a given CustomerID (matched to Customer_input). Customer 12345 has 2 dates that qualify (20140213 and 20120811), but only 20140213 is outputted as it's the closest to the date of interest listed in myInputTable (12345, '20140924')

Comment: This `select Date_of_interest from @myInputTable` is returning multiple results, which doesn't make sense in the context of your query? You can only compare to a single scalar value - which one do you want to use? Providing sample data and desired results will make your question clearer.

Comment: In addition to what Dale said, you could use that subquery if you include a `TOP 1` to force one value, but of course you need to be sure you are getting the right value.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @DaleK and Andrew! I've edited the question to provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: I see now. You need to JOIN `@myInputTable` and not use it in the condition. So for each row in your source table to access both values from your variable table.

Comment: I added an answer but didn't test it. If you can provide with a full working sample I could try in case it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to map each source row to a row from your variable table, you have to do a join and not simply check that a value exists somewhere in it. And as you need just one value per customer, you will need to use `ROW_NUMBER`. Maybe something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      MT.CustomerID,
      MT.PurchaseDate,
      Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MT.CustomerID ORDER BY MT.PurchaseDate DESC)
    FROM MainTable MT
    INNER JOIN @myInputTable IT
      ON MT.CustomerID = IT.Customer_input AND MT.PurchaseDate <= IT.Date_of_interest
) Subquery
WHERE Number = 1
ORDER BY CustomerID, PurchaseDate
```

Comment: Seems like row_number is causing issues in the Where clause. I get the following error: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses. I tried using select top 1, but that only gives me 1 row as result instead of 1 row per customer.

Comment: Right, I think you will need to use a subquery for that then. Check the updated answer, please.

Comment: Stu's query is probably  better, but I will leave this one as an alternative, and also in case the `ROW_NUMBER` example can be of use later in another situation.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest all you need is an inner join and then simple aggregation for your desired results:

```
select m.customerId, Max(PurchaseDate) PurchaseDate
From @myInputTable t 
join MainTable m on m.CustomerID = t.Customer_input and m.PurchaseDate <= t.Date_of_interest
group by m.customerId;
```

Comment: This is probably better than my answer. :D

Comment: Interesting, thanks I'll give this a try too. Andrew's code worked well as well. I would've thought the Max(PurchaseDate) would be performed first prior to the join, but I guess my order of operations was wrong.

Comment: As is usually the case there are many ways to achieve the same output in SQL. Depending on the indexes available and the data cardinality, this method will *probably* be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by inner joining with the table variable and aggregating it.

> ```
> DECLARE @myInputTable TABLE (
>  Customer_input INT, 
>  Date_of_interest INT
> );
> insert into @myInputTable values
>   (12345, '20140924')
> , (22234, '20210508')
> ;
>
> SELECT 
>   t.CustomerID
> , MAX(PurchaseDate) AS PurchaseDate
> FROM MainTable t
> JOIN @myInputTable i
>   ON i.Customer_input = t.CustomerID
>  AND i.Date_of_interest >= t.PurchaseDate
> GROUP BY t.CustomerID, i.Date_of_interest
> ```

> | CustomerID | PurchaseDate |
> | --- | --- |
> | 12345 | 20140213 |
> | 22234 | 20210419 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c13beb74f387b99fefcc4ef596f720d)*

*Side-note : Columns that contain dates should have the DATE datatype.

You can insert dates in the same "yyyyMMdd" format.*

Comment: I think `Date_of_interest` should not be in the group by.